# azure generating false wsdl address

Tags: wsdl, azure

I start my azure application, I browse to the svc file http://127.0.0.1:82/transaction.svc,
and I get the usual:

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to
>   create a client and use it to call the
>   service. You can do this using the
>   svcutil.exe tool from the command line
>   with the following syntax:
>   svcutil.exe
>   http://rzv-pc:5100/Transaction.svc?wsdl

If i go to http://rzv-pc:5100/Transaction.svc?wsdl the age is blank. 
If I go to http://127.0.0.1:82/transaction.svc?wsdl, I get the wsdl but there are still references like

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://rzv-pc:5100/Transaction.svc?xsd=xsd1"
```

I can't use svcutil on any of this links. What is the problem? I use Azure SDK 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

See http://code.msdn.com/wcfazure (particularly the "known issues" page).  The issue stems from the fact that there are two ports involved.  One is the external port (that the load balancer listens on), which is port 82 in your case.  The other is the internal port, that your code listens to on its VM in the cloud, which is port 5100 in your case.

Note that in SDK 1.3, you can specify the localPort attribute on your endpoints, which lets you choose what that internal port is.  You can make it the same as the external port and thus avoid all strangeness.

Comment: I can't find any solution. did anyone have this problem?

Comment: I'm confused.  Did you try what I suggested?  To be even more direct, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure/Wiki/View.aspx?title=KnownIssues&referringTitle=Home is the page I'm referring to, which says exactly how to solve this.  (Or, you can do what I suggest in the second paragraph.)  Both suggestions work.